# Trying to center and scroll text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q6cn3sfb/) (I sampled a little).

```
<body>
  <div class="title">
    <div id="val">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur condimentum ullamcorper magna ut vulputate. Mauris hendrerit neque et risus feugiat aliquet. Donec non ullamcorper justo. In efficitur mauris sagittis neque vulputate sodales. Fusce
      placerat tortor sapien, in posuere ante egestas quis. Ut lobortis semper volutpat. Phasellus enim enim, facilisis non elit in, ultricies efficitur purus. Ut sit amet posuere lorem, vitae aliquet enim. Suspendisse commodo mollis dictum. Nulla facilisi.
      Aenean vitae ante sem. Sed vel lectus tincidunt, interdum erat eu, aliquet leo. Nam at iaculis lectus. Vestibulum dui mi, laoreet id bibendum in, volutpat sit amet eros. Donec nec mattis nisi, id laoreet enim. Cras tristique massa et iaculis consectetur.
      Vivamus gravida consectetur vestibulum. Ut eget orci neque. Aenean eget finibus dui. Vestibulum ac fringilla sem. Morbi venenatis rhoncus dictum. Nulla ac suscipit tortor. Nulla sit amet metus odio. Pellentesque imperdiet laoreet orci, vitae vulputate
      nulla consequat a. Pellentesque tempor lorem sit amet neque aliquam molestie. Ut ultrices vitae felis a blandit. Suspendisse non egestas justo, eget sagittis dolor. Morbi ac blandit ex. Aliquam porta sem quis justo interdum, a venenatis massa blandit.
      Suspendisse feugiat vestibulum eros, vel aliquet nisl porttitor quis. Duis eu dignissim ante. Mauris urna nisl, scelerisque nec eleifend ut, malesuada non urna. Cras a ultricies magna. Donec diam justo, ornare at mauris ac, tempor pretium urna.
      Aenean id consectetur est. Morbi eu libero ultricies, accumsan erat at, efficitur ipsum. Morbi magna risus, rhoncus ac velit mollis, dapibus finibus tortor. Integer lectus odio, vulputate non nibh at, gravida rhoncus lectus. Cras posuere odio luctus
      facilisis varius. Mauris accumsan nunc nisl, vel blandit quam gravida in. Maecenas ac diam eget ante fermentum pretium in ut ex. Phasellus et enim non ligula iaculis pretium. Cras ac lacinia ipsum, non porta nunc. Maecenas id turpis justo. Duis
      nulla turpis, laoreet vitae viverra a, porta et est. Nulla venenatis non erat eu vehicula. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Cras et convallis quam. Curabitur pellentesque mi aliquet aliquet
      condimentum. Duis semper ante et facilisis auctor. Proin turpis est, placerat nec condimentum ac, ornare eget sem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus ligula ex, porta vel magna nec, sodales dapibus augue. Cras auctor
      diam non sem tincidunt aliquam. Curabitur lobortis tortor porta, volutpat mi id, sagittis dolor. Nam rhoncus tortor nec ipsum vulputate, sed fermentum ligula consequat. Fusce ullamcorper augue ac lobortis euismod. Mauris ut mi vitae ipsum accumsan
      commodo. Etiam nunc purus, scelerisque vitae nibh molestie, porttitor gravida ipsum.</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I'm trying to center the text and trying to scroll the text when it overflows. I'm not exactly sure whats wrong. I tried changing the position from absolute to fixed or relative but nothing worked. What am I doing wrong.

Comment: just remove `overflow: hidden` from html? it scrolls and is centered... https://jsfiddle.net/q6cn3sfb/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using in html `overflow:hidden` so change it `overflow:auto`; and your text is already centered.

Update css part

```
html {
  position: relative;
  background: #FF4E50;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #FF4E50, #F9D423);
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #FF4E50, #F9D423);
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  overflow: auto; /*Add this or remove it */
  font-family: Montserrat, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.title {
  /*position: absolute;*/
  /*top: 40%;*/
  /*left: 0;*/
  /*right: 0;*/
  /*-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);*/
  /*transform: translateY(-50%);*/
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 80px;
  text-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
}

html {
  position: relative;
  background: #FF4E50;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #FF4E50, #F9D423);
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #FF4E50, #F9D423);
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  overflow: auto;
  font-family: Montserrat, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.title {
  /*position: absolute;*/
  /*top: 40%;*/
  /*left: 0;*/
  /*right: 0;*/
  /*-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);*/
  /*transform: translateY(-50%);*/
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 80px;
  text-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1000;
}

.title a {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 50px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="title">
    <div id="val">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur condimentum ullamcorper magna ut vulputate. Mauris hendrerit neque et risus feugiat aliquet. Donec non ullamcorper justo. In efficitur mauris sagittis neque vulputate sodales. Fusce
      placerat tortor sapien, in posuere ante egestas quis. Ut lobortis semper volutpat. Phasellus enim enim, facilisis non elit in, ultricies efficitur purus. Ut sit amet posuere lorem, vitae aliquet enim. Suspendisse commodo mollis dictum. Nulla facilisi.
      Aenean vitae ante sem. Sed vel lectus tincidunt, interdum erat eu, aliquet leo. Nam at iaculis lectus. Vestibulum dui mi, laoreet id bibendum in, volutpat sit amet eros. Donec nec mattis nisi, id laoreet enim. Cras tristique massa et iaculis consectetur.
      Vivamus gravida consectetur vestibulum. Ut eget orci neque. Aenean eget finibus dui. Vestibulum ac fringilla sem. Morbi venenatis rhoncus dictum. Nulla ac suscipit tortor. Nulla sit amet metus odio. Pellentesque imperdiet laoreet orci, vitae vulputate
      nulla consequat a. Pellentesque tempor lorem sit amet neque aliquam molestie. Ut ultrices vitae felis a blandit. Suspendisse non egestas justo, eget sagittis dolor. Morbi ac blandit ex. Aliquam porta sem quis justo interdum, a venenatis massa blandit.
      Suspendisse feugiat vestibulum eros, vel aliquet nisl porttitor quis. Duis eu dignissim ante. Mauris urna nisl, scelerisque nec eleifend ut, malesuada non urna. Cras a ultricies magna. Donec diam justo, ornare at mauris ac, tempor pretium urna.
      Aenean id consectetur est. Morbi eu libero ultricies, accumsan erat at, efficitur ipsum. Morbi magna risus, rhoncus ac velit mollis, dapibus finibus tortor. Integer lectus odio, vulputate non nibh at, gravida rhoncus lectus. Cras posuere odio luctus
      facilisis varius. Mauris accumsan nunc nisl, vel blandit quam gravida in. Maecenas ac diam eget ante fermentum pretium in ut ex. Phasellus et enim non ligula iaculis pretium. Cras ac lacinia ipsum, non porta nunc. Maecenas id turpis justo. Duis
      nulla turpis, laoreet vitae viverra a, porta et est. Nulla venenatis non erat eu vehicula. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Cras et convallis quam. Curabitur pellentesque mi aliquet aliquet
      condimentum. Duis semper ante et facilisis auctor. Proin turpis est, placerat nec condimentum ac, ornare eget sem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus ligula ex, porta vel magna nec, sodales dapibus augue. Cras auctor
      diam non sem tincidunt aliquam. Curabitur lobortis tortor porta, volutpat mi id, sagittis dolor. Nam rhoncus tortor nec ipsum vulputate, sed fermentum ligula consequat. Fusce ullamcorper augue ac lobortis euismod. Mauris ut mi vitae ipsum accumsan
      commodo. Etiam nunc purus, scelerisque vitae nibh molestie, porttitor gravida ipsum.</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Removed `position: absolute;` from `.title` and removed `overflow: hidden;` from html

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
}

html {
  position: relative;
  background: #FF4E50;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #FF4E50, #F9D423);
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #FF4E50, #F9D423);
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  font-family: Montserrat, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 80px;
  text-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1000;
}

.title a {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 50px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="title">
    <div id="val">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur condimentum ullamcorper magna ut vulputate. Mauris hendrerit neque et risus feugiat aliquet. Donec non ullamcorper justo. In efficitur mauris sagittis neque vulputate sodales. Fusce
      placerat tortor sapien, in posuere ante egestas quis. Ut lobortis semper volutpat. Phasellus enim enim, facilisis non elit in, ultricies efficitur purus. Ut sit amet posuere lorem, vitae aliquet enim. Suspendisse commodo mollis dictum. Nulla facilisi.
      Aenean vitae ante sem. Sed vel lectus tincidunt, interdum erat eu, aliquet leo. Nam at iaculis lectus. Vestibulum dui mi, laoreet id bibendum in, volutpat sit amet eros. Donec nec mattis nisi, id laoreet enim. Cras tristique massa et iaculis consectetur.
      Vivamus gravida consectetur vestibulum. Ut eget orci neque. Aenean eget finibus dui. Vestibulum ac fringilla sem. Morbi venenatis rhoncus dictum. Nulla ac suscipit tortor. Nulla sit amet metus odio. Pellentesque imperdiet laoreet orci, vitae vulputate
      nulla consequat a. Pellentesque tempor lorem sit amet neque aliquam molestie. Ut ultrices vitae felis a blandit. Suspendisse non egestas justo, eget sagittis dolor. Morbi ac blandit ex. Aliquam porta sem quis justo interdum, a venenatis massa blandit.
      Suspendisse feugiat vestibulum eros, vel aliquet nisl porttitor quis. Duis eu dignissim ante. Mauris urna nisl, scelerisque nec eleifend ut, malesuada non urna. Cras a ultricies magna. Donec diam justo, ornare at mauris ac, tempor pretium urna.
      Aenean id consectetur est. Morbi eu libero ultricies, accumsan erat at, efficitur ipsum. Morbi magna risus, rhoncus ac velit mollis, dapibus finibus tortor. Integer lectus odio, vulputate non nibh at, gravida rhoncus lectus. Cras posuere odio luctus
      facilisis varius. Mauris accumsan nunc nisl, vel blandit quam gravida in. Maecenas ac diam eget ante fermentum pretium in ut ex. Phasellus et enim non ligula iaculis pretium. Cras ac lacinia ipsum, non porta nunc. Maecenas id turpis justo. Duis
      nulla turpis, laoreet vitae viverra a, porta et est. Nulla venenatis non erat eu vehicula. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Cras et convallis quam. Curabitur pellentesque mi aliquet aliquet
      condimentum. Duis semper ante et facilisis auctor. Proin turpis est, placerat nec condimentum ac, ornare eget sem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus ligula ex, porta vel magna nec, sodales dapibus augue. Cras auctor
      diam non sem tincidunt aliquam. Curabitur lobortis tortor porta, volutpat mi id, sagittis dolor. Nam rhoncus tortor nec ipsum vulputate, sed fermentum ligula consequat. Fusce ullamcorper augue ac lobortis euismod. Mauris ut mi vitae ipsum accumsan
      commodo. Etiam nunc purus, scelerisque vitae nibh molestie, porttitor gravida ipsum.</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course so easy!

change

```
<div id="val">
```

to

```
<div id="val" align="center">
```

and move from you css html {}

```
overflow: hidden;
```

to you css body

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

and add a new object in you css with, val

```
#val {
    overflow: y;
}
```

enjoy of this code.